# Strategy to create task scheduler

Tags: algorithm, mobile, server, scheduled-tasks

I am creating an App which allows users to schedule repeated task with friends. I am thinking of ways to create the scheduling queue.

The first way would be to let the task be handled by the server. The task can be created and the scheduling algorithm would run on the server which will send notifications to the involved users. The problem with this approach is that it would overload the server if many users would be using it.

The second approach would be to let the user app handle the task scheduling on their mobile as a background service, this would be ideal as it would not overload the server. The disadvantage of this approach would be that the notifications would depend on the status of the user phone(Internet connection, on/off, etc...).

Which of the two methods would be ideal, or is there some other way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would be an adept of running this on the server, because of the following advantages:

- only one place to keep all the details for one notification (*e.g.* message text, schedule). This ensures that we don't somehow end up with clients having different notification data in their client applications. This results in simpler logic if the notification details can be updated, or new friends can be added. Although sometimes underestimated, I think that simplicity should be an important criterion in the architecture choice.
- it seems that it is relatively easy to scale horizontally -- multiple message queues can be set up on multiple machines, without interference between the queues.

Comment: How about keeping the notification details on the server and just keeping the scheduler on the app. This would make sure that notification data remains same

Comment: I was thinking that the notification details also include aspects important for the scheduler, _e.g._ notification interval. In such a case, the notification interval would need to be maintained on the client apps, running into difficulties mentioned in my post.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have chosen in the end? Are you happy with the decision?